# Should I use parameters in template scripting to control the output, or a separate specialized template?

Tags: javascript, templates, backbone.js, underscore.js

Would it be considered best practice to use a single template that changes it's output based on script values, or have multiple templates, and use the view to pick the correct one instead?

For example, in this underscope template:

```
<script type="text/template" id="SkillsetTemplate">

<div class='RegularMode <%= (skillset.get('InEditMode')===false)?'show':'hide' %>'>
</div>

<div class='EditMode <%= (skillset.get('InEditMode')===true)?'show':'hide' %>'>
</div>

</script>
```

I use a backbone model to bind against, and use the `InEditMode` attribute to pick which content to render.

Should I instead have a normal mode, and an edit mode template, and use the attribute on the model to pick the template ?

For background purposes, I am using backbone.js with underscore templates and an MVC3 backend.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd absolutely go with a second template. I'll admit it may not be completely DRY but you never know, you may need the edit template to not look a bit like your non-edit one (in which case you aren't repeating yourself).

Comment: I'll admit, there might be some example where it may be beneficial to go with some base template for both modes, but I'm having trouble imagining it.

Comment: Well, if I could imagine it,  it'd have to be something similar to Knockout.JS's implementation for Backbone.js or something....